# How can I Remove CodeClimate similar code from strong params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, dry

I'm analyzing my code in CodeClimate.com and I have a similar code problem always in the same lines:

```
params.permit(some parameters here)
```

CodeClimate is detecting this code as similar based only in the mass of the code, not in the content, so my quality is not improving due to this.

Is there a way to tell CodeClimate that this code is not repeated or even similar, as long as it's a parameters hash?

Comment: Does not look like this is possible: https://twitter.com/codeclimate/status/422124396988624896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to refactor such issues? Say, you have code:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def resource_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end
end

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def resource_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :email, :body)
  end
end
```

You can move repeating code into superclass, leaving in subclasses only differences:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionControllerBase
  # ...

  def resource_params
    params.require(resource_name).permit(*permitted_resource_params)
  end
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def resource_name
    :post
  end

  def permitted_resource_params
    [:title, :body]
  end
end

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def resource_name
    :comment
  end

  def permitted_resource_params
    [:name, :email, :body]
  end
end
```

And, of course, if in some controller you have different rules of params permission — you could redefine `resource_params` method in it.

Comment: I don't think that changing the rails convention just to avoid a problem in a rating tool might be a solution. But i really like this solution for this kind of similar mass problem. Thanks.

Comment: While solving the rating tool issue, this just makes the code harder (not easier) to grok as it departs from standard conventions for the framework.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to avoid this kind of codeclimate problem as long as it is not discriminating the name of the method, just the mass of it.

Edit 2020:

Apparently this issue is happening in every modern linter. They just check that there's a huge set of lines repeated in different files, and mark them as a possible duplicates. And it happens on every other language. Specially the ones that are interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

As MikiDiet suggested, probably the best is to do refactor. But this suggestion won't solve issue completely.  From my experience then CodeClimate will report code smells on:

```
def resource_name
 :post
end

def permitted_resource_params
  [:title, :body]
end
```

as code duplication across controllers.